# htaccess rewrite stopped working properly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code block in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)2021layout(.*)$
[other directories to omit, like assets and admin]
RewriteRule ^(.*) RESThandler.php
```

Basically I want certain directories to be processed normally, like 2021layout, while others use the REST handler. In the 2021layout directory, the member area is in the directory 2021layout/myaccount, and all css/js files are in 2021layout/assets/[whatever directory]. Both the assets and myaccount directories have permissions 0755.

On Friday, everything was working fine. Today, **having changed nothing**, pages in the 2021layout directory are working, and css and js files loaded by those pages are fine, but pages in the 2021layout/myaccount directory are trying to use the REST handler and getting redirected to my 404 page.

I have tried renaming both the 2021layout and myaccount directories, which didn't work. I have tried adding `!^(.*)2021layout/myaccount(.*)$` as a RewriteCond, and that didn't work.

Why would this one specific directory suddenly stop obeying my htaccess instructions? Can I fix this?

Again, to reiterate: I didn't change anything to make this happen. It worked one day, and the next day it didn't, seemingly on its own.

EDIT: I have gotten the directory to work again by renaming the newly-created file settings.php to mysettings.php. So apparently the mere existence of settings.php within the directory was preventing it from loading correctly. Does anyone have any insight into this?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this rule with `THE_REQUEST`:

```sh
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/2021layout/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ RESThandler.php [L]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of other rewrite directives. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

---

> So apparently the mere existence of `settings.php` within the directory was preventing it from loading correctly. Does anyone have any insight into this

I am guessing that you have option `MultiViews` turned on in your Apache config. To turn it off use this directive at top of your .htaccess:

```sh
Option -MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.

Comment: Also please provide your full .htaccess in question

Comment: Please see my revised question. The last paragraph is very important.